# Matlab - Renaming files sequentially (Opposite direction)

Tags: matlab, file, rename

I Have sequential files for example:

hi_0001.edf

hi_0002.edf

hi_0003.edf

hi_0004.edf

I want to rename them plus number them the opposite direction (Start from end to beginning) so that:

"hi_**0001**.edf" becomes "hello_**0004**.edf"

"hi_**0002**.edf" becomes "hello_**0003**.edf"

"hi_**0003**.edf" becomes "hello_**0002**.edf"

"hi_**0004**.edf" becomes "hello_**0001**.edf"

I have the following program that can rename the files but gives them the same numbers (From beginning to end):

```
%//' Directory where TIFF images are present
directory  = 'C:\Users\opd28\Desktop\folder\'; 

%//' files pattern with absolute paths
filePattern = fullfile(directory, 'hi_*.edf'); 

%// Get the filenames
old_filename = cellstr(ls(filePattern)) ;

%// Get numbers associated with each file
file_ID = strrep(strrep(old_filename,'hi_',''),'.edf','');

file_ID_doublearr = str2double(file_ID);
file_ID_doublearr = file_ID_doublearr - min(file_ID_doublearr)+1;

file_ID = strtrim(cellstr(num2str(file_ID_doublearr)));

%// Get zeros string to be pre-appended to each filename
str_zeros = arrayfun(@(t) repmat('0',1,t),4-cellfun(@numel,file_ID),'uni',0) ;

%// Generate new filenames
new_filename = strcat('hello_',str_zeros,file_ID,'.edf') ;

%// Finally rename files with the absolute paths
cellfun(@(m1,m2)movefile(m1,m2),fullfile(directory,old_filename),fullfile(directory,new_filename)) ;
```

The code above generates the following:

"hi_**0001**.edf" becomes "hello_**0001**.edf"

"hi_**0002**.edf" becomes "hello_**0002**.edf"

"hi_**0003**.edf" becomes "hello_**0003**.edf"

"hi_**0004**.edf" becomes "hello_**0004**.edf"

What do I need to add to make the new file names start from the end towards the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [flip](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) the `file_ID_doublearr` variable, and you'll have it.

```
file_ID_doublearr = str2double(file_ID);
file_ID = file_ID_doublearr(end:-1:1);   % or 'flipud' / 'fliplr'
```

Now you can finish with the rest of your script, and the file names should be ordered from 4 to 1.

I guess this is the line where you tried to change the numbers:

```
file_ID_doublearr = max(file_ID_doublearr) - file_ID_doublearr + 1;
```

If you did one of the following, it would have worked:

```
file_ID_doublearr = file_ID_doublearr - min(file_ID_doublearr)+1;
```

or

```
file_ID_doublearr = flipud(file_ID_doublearr);
```

<sub>Note, I don't have MATLAB here, but I can't imagine this not working. Please let me know if there's an error.</sub>